# using the 'ptw' package in R

Tags: r

I am working on applying the `ptw` package to my GC-MS wine data.  So far I have been able to correctly use this package on the apples example data described in the vignette (MTBLS99).  Since I am new to R, I am unable to get my .CDF files into the format they used to start the vignette.  They started with three data frames (`All.pks, All.tics, All.xset`).  I assume that this was generated using the `xcms` package.  But I cannot recreate the specific steps used for the data to be formatted in this manner.  Has anyone successfully applied 'ptw' to their LC/GC-MS data? can someone share the code used for generating the All.pks, All.tics, All.xset data frames?